# Equations involving squaring a variable under a radical sign

Tags: radical-equations

If anyone can help me with how to go about solving these kind of equations i would really appreciate it. :-)

$$\sqrt{36-2x^2} = 4$$

Solve for X

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is how to use MathJax.

Comment: Thank you Toby!

Answer (score 0):

$36-2x^2 = 16$

$\frac{36-16}{2} = x^2$

$x= \pm \sqrt{10}.$

Comment: Thank you so much! Huge help.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at how to get rid of the square root sign on the left-hand side of the equation. Then I would look at isolating your variable, i.e. x. What did you attempt already?

Answer (score 0):

Square both sides:

$$36-2x^2=16$$
$$ -2x^2+20=0$$
$$ 2x^2-20=0$$
$$x^2-10=0$$
$$x = ±\sqrt{10}$$

Now we need to check for extraneous solutions. You can then substitute these values of $x$ in the LHS, and check they equal the RHS.

Comment: Thank you Toby! I had got to $$x^2-10=0$$ and then i got stuck. I'm new to Maths. I didn't realise i could have a radical sign in my answer. That's a huge help!

Comment: @MirandaWolf That's why it's always better to show your work! If you had just said that in your question, I would only need the last few lines of my answer.

Comment: I hadn't worked out the formatting to type my working out on here, but i have now thanks to you. :-)